# Looking for a written corpus composed of a H-M dialogue

Tags: dialog-acts

I'm a student in applied linguistics and i'm looking for a corpus that contains H-M conversation for an analysis purpose. The user must have the possibility to answer what he wants to the machine. Do you know a website where i could find something interesting? Thank you =)

---

I would like to find a dialog with a travel\insurance agent or some other kind. 
Eliza is a therapist chatbot, the conversation is not super exiting. 
I'm looking for errors that are generated by the machine. 
Why It doesn't understand the task of the user? It's the question that i'm asking myself. Sometimes it's due to syntactic or semantic problems for example.
=)

Comment: Any particular type of human-machine conversation you're looking for? For example, I would assume there are ELIZA transcripts out there, and Alexa transcripts out there, which will look quite different.

Comment: I would like to find a dialog with a travel\insurance agent or some other kind. Eliza is a therapist chatbot, the conversation is not super exiting. I'm looking for errors that are generated by the machine. Why It doesn't understand the task of the user? It's the question that i'm asking myself. Sometimes it's due to syntactic or semantic problems for example. =)